# How to lock pages in memory using WinAPI?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, real-time

I need to prevent application's memory pages from being swapped out of RAM on Windows. Is there a WinAPI function equivalent of POSIX [`mlockall()`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/mlockall.html) to achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, VirtualLock().  There's a limit on how many pages you can lock, you can't hog RAM.  Details are in the [MSDN article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366895%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have to ask, why do you need to do this? If every app thought its pages were so important that they shouldn't be paged out ever, it would be a giant waste of memory.

If the pages are in use, they *won't* be sent to the pagefile, and if they're not in use, why keep them around? Trust in Mm, it was written by [a very smart guy](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/exec/de/Wang/default.mspx) :)

Comment: It is true for most applications, but I am writing a very specific application where I need to be guaranteed not to incur latency from page faults.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Maybe we can give you a better answer if you describe the scenario more...

Comment: dude! Windows is NOT a realtime OS. The latency from pagefaults is going to be small compared to the many many other sources of latency and interruption on the system.

Comment: Luckily, I just need it for some testing.

Comment: Locking can be used to prevent sensitive data from being swapped onto disk.

Comment: This answer should be a comment, not a top-level reply. There are many valid reasons to lock a page from being paged - for one example, you can prevent secret keys from being copied to disk, opening yourself to a range of forensic attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can set the windows option of lock pages in memory. Usually this setting is mostly used by SQL Server, but works also for other applications. Check this site on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190730.aspx)

enable addressing windows extensions (AWE) for your application. See this link on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366527(VS.85).aspx)